# Can I download and split video with python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, download, youtube

I made some script to download and split the video into smaller clips but I have a problem. Python can not do with space and I can not rename a video before downloading it.

```
video = pytube.YouTube(link)
video.filename(tepm)
'YouTube' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

But if I kept the title in the original FFmpeg can not read it because in the title of the video are splits

```
def downloadVideo(link):
    
    video = pytube.YouTube(link)
    video.filename(word)
    stream = video.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    
    
    stream.download()
    

# pass the youtube video link to download
downloadVideo(video_url)

print("video is downloaded")



#Cut video
os.system("ffmpeg -i "+  +".mp4" + " -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:00:30 -f segment - 
reset_timestamps 1 output%%.mp4")
```

Answer (score 0):

The video or title should be in double quote **""**. As ffmpeg command is being written as batch command. bat files dont support white spaces. It should be like this.

```
"\"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\code\\YT downloader\\Download\\file name\"" #using \" to place quotes
```

Here if **\"** is not used then the following would be considered one thing.

```
C:\\Users\\Desktop\\code\\YT
```

and this would be considered the other

```
downloader\\Download\\file
```

and *name* would be other.
The other thing that would bother is **special characters in title.** ffmpeg will give error if there is special character in file name. I dont know the reason but you can fix it like this

```
    char = "|/<>?,:'}{][+_-=)(*&%$#@!~`"
    for c in char:
        title = title.replace(c , "")
```

I which characters are actually supported and which are not. I added according to my thinking and it is working.

**The answer to the question can be.**

the file name can be changed by using this command.

```
stream.download(filename="vid.mp4")
```

As far I know this is the method to rename video in pytube